What size should the background image be so it is not scaled?
What dimensions should an image file have so that it will not be scaled when set as a wallpaper for the lockscreen or homescreen?
This question is NOT the same as What is the default resolution of a wallpaper that fits the homescreen exactly in an Android phone?. I only have a single home screen.
I already tried the dimensions of the screen. That does not work since the image is zoomed in slightly, so that it can be zoomed out when pulling down the notifications menu.
On my phone, the Nokia 5.4, the screen resolution is 720x1560.
My best guess at the best wallpaper resolution is 792x1778, however that size is still not perfect.

It sounds like your phone will scale the image regardless, but here are a few options you can try:

See if there are any scaling options
Check for a scrolling background option and fiddle with it until it doesn't scale
Edit the image to have a border around what you don't want scaled to a point where the border is off-screen. This can be done on a computer with GIMP (free) or Photoshop (paid)
Check your settings for a "reduce motion" option

If you need help with option 3, I'd be happy to make some test images.

Option 3 is what I tried already, it gets tedious quickly. I checked option 4, this particular animation can't be disabled.
But option 2 lead me in the right direction. Whilst there are no options when setting the wallpaper from the gallery, I was able to use a live wallpaper app to set a static image.

The particular app I used is https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lb.lwp_plus, but there are probably loads others that do the same thing.

If you want, you can try screenshotting the image and see if that works, and then putting it as the wallpaper.
I did that with my iPhone and Android device, and it usually just puts it scaled. For example, the Samsung Galaxy Note 3 is 1900x1080, so it would be the size for the wallpaper, and if the image is scaled to that, it should fully display without any problems.

If you have a computer that is 15 inch, usually it would be 1366x768 so if you have an image that exact size it will be fully displayed. Same concept as the phone, most phones, and hopefully yours to.

No, this does not work. As I mentioned, the image will be zoomed in to accomodate the "zoom out" animation when sliding down the notifications.
